# MVC autocomplete not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I know there are lot of posts out there but simply I can not figure out what I am doing wrong in autocomplete.

I have a ProductController like

```
public JsonResult AutocompleteMethod(string searchstring) //searchString null here
        {
              Product ob=new Product();
              List<Product> newLst = ob.GetProducts();
              var suggestions = from s in newLst select s.productName ;
              var namelist = suggestions.Where(n=>n.StartsWith(searchstring));
              return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
```

In view I have:

```
    <p>
        Find by name:<%: Html.TextBox("Txt") %>
    </p>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


     <script type="text/jscript">
         $(function () {
             debugger;

             $('#Txt').autocomplete({ source: '/Product/AutocompleteMethod' });

         });
     </script>
```

But always **SearchString** is `NULL` in controller function.

Can you figure out what is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the parameter is called `term`, not `searchstring`, so:

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteMethod(string term)
{
    List<Product> newLst = new Product().GetProducts();
    var namelist = 
        from p in newLst 
        where p.StartsWith(term)
        select new 
        {
            value = p.Id, // you might need to adjust the Id property name here to match your model
            label = p.productName
        };
    return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also I very much doubt that `productName` is a property that the autocomplete plugin will ever recognize. You could try using `value` and `label` as shown in the projection I performed in my example.